# Unusued char [] variable bleeding into next variable

Tags: c

Coding along to [learn c the hardway ex8](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex8.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int areas[5] = {10, 12, 13, 14, 20};
  char name[] = "h";
  char full_name[] = {
    'f', 'o', 'o',
    ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r'
  };

  printf("The size of an int: %ld\n", sizeof(int));
  printf("The size of areas (int[]): %ld\n", sizeof(areas));
  printf("The first area is %d, the 2nd is %d.\n", areas[0], areas[1]);
  printf("Their respective sizes are: %ld, %ld.\n", sizeof(areas[0]), sizeof(areas[1]));

  printf("The size of a char: %ld\n", sizeof(char));
  printf("The size of name(char[]): %ld\n", sizeof(name));
  printf("The number of chars: %ld\n", sizeof(name) / sizeof(char));
  printf("The size of full_name (char[]): %ld\n", sizeof(full_name));
  printf("The number of chars: %ld\n", sizeof(full_name) / sizeof(char));

  printf("full_name: %s", full_name);

  printf("name=\"%s\" and full_name=\"%s\"\n", name, full_name);

  return 0;
}
```

I expect to not have the char name[] = "h" affect anything. Yet it bleeds into full_name.

```
./ex8
The size of an int: 4
The size of areas (int[]): 20
The first area is 10, the 2nd is 12.
Their respective sizes are: 4, 4.
The size of a char: 1
The size of full_name (char[]): 7
The number of chars: 7
full_name: foo barhname="h" and full_name="foo barh"
```

See the last line.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably some combination of `full_name` not being null-terminated and  it happening to be next to `name` on the stack. Don't remember enough of the spec to be sure if this always happens, hence why this isn't an answer. (Actually, judging from the answers, it's not guaranteed to happen at all.)

Comment: Your code does not match your output.
In particular, the code has `The size of name(char[]): %ld\n`.  Your output does not have a matching line.

Comment: @DennisMeng that was it! I missed the \0 in the example.

Comment: You have not null-terminated full_name.

Comment: The output you provided does not match the code you provided.

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, that 'h' isn't coming from `name`.  It's just random garbage that happens to be an 'h'.

`%s` in printf expects a null-terminated string.  You don't have a `\0` at the end of `full_name`, so it just keeps reading extra memory, which happens to have an h in it.

Change your declaration of `full_name` and you're good to go:

```
  char full_name[] = {
    'f', 'o', 'o',
    ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'
  };
```

**EDIT** After quantumpotato verified, I'll admit - I was wrong in saying that the garbage is random.  AndreyT explained that the stack can load "backwards", and so the 'h' came from `name`, which had the next memory position in the stack.  I will still stress that this is compiler-dependent, and accessing beyond an array's length leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Interesting assertion. Perhaps the OP could change the 'h' to an 'x' to see whether your claim of unrelatedness to 'name' is false (I bet it is).

Comment: @RonBurk That would be interesting, but at best it would be informative about the compiler.  What really matters is that OP's string is not properly terminated, resulting in the `printf` exceeding the bounds of its array and yielding undefined behavior.  It *may* be that this specific compiler builds the stack upside down, but typically `name` would have an earlier address than `full_name`.  A better way to test your theory would be to simply print the addresses of the two variables.

Comment: I would guess that that `h` is not random. That `h` is actually from `name`. `name` happens to be located after `full_name` in memory, as on many platforms local variables are stored "in reverse order" in memory.

Comment: I'll have to yield to you and @RonBurk on that.  I was willing to accept the 1:256 coincidence of an 'h' being next, but the 1:65536 chance of it being "h\0" makes it more likely that you're right.

Comment: The h is not random. char name[] = "hi"; yields full_name: foo barhi
name="hi" and full_name="foo barhi"

Answer (score 3):

```
char full_name[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r' };
...
printf("full_name: %s", full_name);
```

The `"%s"` format requires a pointer to a string. The `char` array `full_name` does not contain a string, because it's not terminated by a `'\0'` null character.

`printf` will probably continue printing characters in memory until it happens to find a null character, but the bottom line is that the behavior is undefined.

If you defined `full_name` with a string literal, it would be properly null-terminated:

```
char full_name[] = "foo bar";
```

Comment: I obviously didn't upvote it myself, but IMHO the real issue is that `fulL_name` is not null-terminated. Which particular chunk of memory beyond the end of `full_name` happens to be accessed is incidental.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, on your platform local variables are allocated in reverse order in memory.

This means that array `full_name` gets lower memory address than array `name`, i.e. `name` follows `full_name` in memory. When you attempt to output array `full_name` as a string, `printf` crosses the boundary of `full_name`, since you forgot to zero-terminate it. It enters the `name` area and also outputs that `h` from `name`, finally stopping at zero-terminator from `name`.